# getAnnotations() is empty and not working as expected

Tags: java, annotations

I am expecting this code:

```
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.lang.annotation.Retention;
import java.lang.annotation.RetentionPolicy;

@Retention(RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME)
@interface Sometation {}


public class Test {
    @Sometation
    public static void main(String[] args) {
     System.out.println(Arrays.toString(Test.class.getAnnotations()));
     System.out.println(Arrays.toString(Test.class.getDeclaredAnnotations()));
    }

}
```

to result in at least one nonempty array. Instead it results in

```
[]
[]
```

This happens in eclipse and when I run it in terminal. I am running 'java-8-openjdk-amd64' (installed by apt on UbuntuMATE 16.04).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You've annotated the `main()` *method*, not the `Test` class.  The class `Test` has no annotations.  To see the annotation that you've added, you'd need to get the method first, and then use [Method#getDeclaredAnnotations()](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/reflect/Method.html#getDeclaredAnnotations--).  Something like (untested):

```
Test.class.getMethod("main", String[].class).getDeclaredAnnotations()
```

Alternatively, you could put the annotation on the class:

```
@Sometation
public class Test { ... }
```

and then your original code should display some non-empty arrays.